# nginx rewrite does not working unexpected

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

this is my nginx rewrite rule:

rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ /index.php?app=$1&action=$2;

visit /test/test/ it works, but visit /test/ it does not rewrite to /index.php?app=test&action=

and var_dump($_GET) print: array(1) { ["q"]=> string(6) "/test/" }

but $_GET['q'] does not defined, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it won't match the rule, your rule only works if there is only an app AND action, you can either  write another rule to match when the action is missing, or specify that the second part is optional
try this rule instead

```
rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)? /index.php?app=$1&action=$2;
```